# Share methods between ActiveModels

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple problem, but I don't know what the best approach is to do it.

I have two ActiveModel classes (say SimpleUser and User). I'd like to share some method implementations between them (say a full_name method that aggregates first name and last name, to stay simple).

In a classical OO language, I'd have used an abstract class that my two classes would have extended. But in Ruby (and even Rails), what's the best approach?

Answer (score 3):

You can put your code in the `app/models/concerns` and include them in both models.
For example:

- app/models/concerns/user/shared_methods.rb

```rb
module Concerns::User::SharedMethods
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def full_name
    ...
  end
end
```

- app/models/user.rb

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Concerns::User::SharedMethods
  ...
end
```

- app/models/simple_user.rb

```rb
class SimpleUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Concerns::User::SharedMethods
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

- You could create a module, e.g UserAttributes, which would be included in each User class
- Or you could create a base class as in conventional object-oriented language and use it as an abstract class. If you want to make sure that no one misuses it, you could make it's constructor private.

It would look like this:

```
class User
  private_class_method :new
end
```

Note: In ActiveRecord (not ActiveModel) there is a built-in way to make class abstract.

```
self.abstract_class = true
```